# Beveling loose edges on Blender 2.80

Tags: modeling, edges, bevel

I'm wondering how to perform the operation on the selected vertex (left) that will result in the curve on the right:

[image]

Yes, those are loose edges. I tried the Bevel Tool and Ctrl+B, but they'll only operate in fully formed faces/edges.

I saw a teammate do this very operation with Blender 2.79 (I'm on 2.80) but he couldn't even name the operation, just a complex shortcut.

By the way: I'll want to transform this edge mesh in tubes, later!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enabling *Vertex Only* in the properties of the bevel tool allows you to bevel the edge. You can also enable it in the *Adjust Last Operation* panel. The shortcut is <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>.

[image]